# Why is the birthday slightly different in Ishay Ribo's "Keter Melucha"?

Tags: song-lyrics, hebrew-language, ishay-ribo

In Ishay Ribo's "Keter Melucha / כתר מלוכה" (a song written in early 2020 about lockdown in Israel), the opening stanza goes like this:

> בין תרומה לתצווה
> יום הולדת קצת משונה
> הכל רגיל כאן לכאורה
> במה קהל ואהבה
>
> Between T'rumah and Tetzaveh
> A birthday slightly strange
> Everything normal for the moment
> Stage, crowd, and love
> <sub>(my own translation)</sub>

The timeframe given is in [February](https://www.hebcal.com/sedrot/terumah-20200229), during which time Israel was still operating largely normally. Ishay Ribo's birthday is, indeed, in February.

Why would he say "a birthday slightly strange" and then immediately afterwards "everything normal for the moment"? If something was off - e.g. a birthday not fully celebrated due to virus concerns - why would he say that everything is normal immediately after?

Comment: לכאורה means "apparently" or "at first glance," not "for the moment"